# Odd behaviour with animation scrubbing and animator triggers in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

Is anyone able to tell me why my triggers don't work when I use this script? 
this is used in conjunction with a slider to scrub through the playback of an animation:

```
public class AnimatorControl : MonoBehaviour
{

public Animator anim;
public Slider slider;   //Assign the UI slider of your scene in this slot 
//public string animatorClipName;
Animator m_Animator;
public int i;
string m_ClipName;
AnimatorClipInfo[] m_CurrentClipInfo;
float m_CurrentClipLength;
float timer;
// public int currentFrame;
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    //Get them_Animator, which you attach to the GameObject you intend to animate.
    m_Animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    //Fetch the current Animation clip information for the base layer
    m_CurrentClipInfo = this.m_Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0);
    //Access the current length of the clip
    m_CurrentClipLength = m_CurrentClipInfo[0].clip.length;
    //Access the Animation clip name
    m_ClipName = m_CurrentClipInfo[0].clip.name;


    timer = (1 / m_CurrentClipLength) / 60;

}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    int currentFrame = (int)(m_CurrentClipInfo[0].weight * (m_CurrentClipInfo[0].clip.length * 
    m_CurrentClipInfo[0].clip.frameRate));
    int w = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0).Length;
    string[] clipName = new string[w];
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) anim.SetTrigger("Next");
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i += 1)
    {
        clipName[i] = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0)[i].clip.name;
        Debug.Log(clipName[i]);
        string clip = clipName[i].ToString();
       // anim.Play(clip, 0, slider.normalizedValue);
    }
  //  Debug.Log(m_CurrentClipInfo[0].clip.name);
    slider.normalizedValue += timer;

}
```

}

I am using the spacebar to tigger an animation transition in the animator, which works.
When I use  `anim.Play(clip, 0, slider.normalizedValue);` my triggers will not work.
If i remove  `anim.Play(clip, 0, slider.normalizedValue);`  the triggers begin to work again...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling:

```
// anim.Play(clip, 0, slider.normalizedValue);
```

from your update loop. That means at the start of every frame you are calling it, so it doesn't matter if your trigger fires or not, immediately after in the next frame

```
anim.Play(clip, 0, slider.normalizedValue);
```

is called again. Take it out of the update loop and call it from somewhere else.

Comment: I am having the same result after I created a new function and called the function with the `OnValueChanged` method on the slider. What would be another way to call `anim.Play(clip, 0, slider.normalizedValue); ` ?

Comment: Your slider value is also being incremented every frame on the update loop so it would still call the anim.Play(clip, 0, slider.normalizedValue) every frame. Its playing every frame because of slider.normalizedValue += timer;